# SingleTask Activity android + recreate that Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

There are 2 activities. A and B.

First Activity is A (it has been configured with some stuff from de Bundle of the Intent...

A -> B 
B->A (starting new Activity, not onBackPressed()).Activity A need to be recreated, Intent's Bundle has changed. It also has to be singleTask.

B to A should recreate A Activity, I don't want to use the onResume() of Activity A.

EDIT: It's like whatsapp.
You are in a group->settings->infoGroup->member click->send message
It starts the same activity (Chat Activity), but when you go back the group chat Activity doesn't exist.

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you using SingleTask in the first place? It sounds like that's not what you want.

Comment: CLEAR_TOP flag may be helpful

Comment: @DeeV because I only need 1 "A" Activity.

Comment: edited with an example

Comment: If A starts B with the intention of having B change things in A, use `startActivityForResult`, and handle what has been done in `onActivityResult` in A. No need to restart A.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem well but you can use `onNewIntent:`

If you just want to recreate Activity A for the data which you pass with bundle to when you start from B you can you can override `onNewIntent` method of Activity A, get bundle and do your staff.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    initLayout();
}
```

Your onCreate method can be like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   setContentView(R.id.your_layout);
   // find views;
   initLayout();
}

public void initLayout(){
    final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
       // init layout
       // do other staff
    }
}
```

I think this is the best way to handle your issue.

Good Luck.

Comment: I do a lot of stuff in the onCreate of the method. I don't think this is the best option...

Answer (score 0):

For this,Use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and in `manifest` `launchMode` of your activity `singleinstance`

while going from B --> A using CLick

Comment: No, because maybe I go back with onBackPressed and A activity would be killed.